# DirectX project template not visible in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, directx, directx-11

I want to create DirectX project but template is not visible in any card in New project window on Visual Studio 2017 (community edition) (not only Windows Desktop like on screenshot).

[image]

I would expect something like that:

[image]

I have installed **Game development with C++** (C++ profiling tools and Windows 10 STD) and **Desktop development with C++**.

I've already reinstalled packages and Visual Studio using Visual Studio Installer with no effect so any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Did they ever had such a template? I think I saw UWP directx app template, but never desktop directx. I think you can just start with an empty project or maybe with windows desktop application.

Comment: yeah, template exists, I've updated my question with photo.

Comment: https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those Direct3D Game templates are from this [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates). You get them by installing [this VSIX](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/raw/may2019b/VSIX/Direct3DUWPGame.vsix).

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/) and the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).